# Variables in foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, loops

I have never been good at using loops. I have the following problem:

When I execute the code below, I get this error message: `"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in XXXXXXXXX on line 8"`. I just want to give each of the elements in the array a "rating" on how high the value is.

```
    <?
    $input = array( 12413535, 13452465246, -13451, 8);
    $input_size = count($input);
    $var_rating = array ();
    foreach ($input as $value) {
        $var_rating[$value] = 0;
        foreach ($input as $test) {
            if ($value > $test) {
                $var_rating[$value] = $var_rating[$value] + 1;
            }
            else {}
        }
    }

    var_dump($var_rating);
?>
```

Sorry for the confusion. I edited my question and added the full code.

Comment: That's intersting, I get *PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in XXXXXXXXX on line 1*. It seems you code does not have too much in common with what you ran to get the error message.

Comment: @Oswald: did you copied dots also?

Comment: I can see that there is no syntax error for this part of your code...

Comment: Yes. If I don't, I don't get any parse error.

Comment: @Jan Bayram: your code actually executes without errors, if `$input` is initialized. 
@Oswald: you've probably copied the ellipsis as well )

Comment: @Oswald .. Why?  The dots represent more code above..  I don't understand why you would copy them..

Comment: @Jan: please show how the `$input` array looks like.

Comment: Oh, sorry for making it more complicated. This is on the line 8: if ($value > $test).

Comment: Are you sure? Apart from the dots at the beginning, your code is syntactically correct.

Comment: @Oswald That is what ellipsis represent.  The dots refer to more code above.. they are not apart of the code.

Comment: @Oswald: The dots in the beginning were there just to show that it was just a part of a code. I updated my answer.

Comment: Are you sure the code this error refers to is the one you posted?

Comment: @DamienPirsy: I'm totally sure it is.

Comment: But there are no errors there. Other than, perhaps, `short_open_tags` being turned off? Try changing `<?` to `<?php`...

Comment: @JanBayram Do you include this code anywhere?  If so, please post that.

Comment: OK, so the file is called arrays.php and the output can be found here: http://bayram.moxo.cz/arrays.php

Comment: @JanBayram Can you delete that entire line, and re-type it from scratch?

Comment: @Daedalus: +1 for your last comment!

Comment: Jan, can you zip that file and provide us the link!

Comment: @Akam Here you go. http://www.filedropper.com/arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear the culprit to your code not working is a copied hidden hidden character on line 8, just before the `$test` variable.  Deleting the 'space' and the `>` sign, and retyping both fixes your issue on my end.

```
<?php
    $input = array( 12413535, 13452465246, -13451, 8);
    $input_size = count($input);
    $var_rating = array ();
    foreach ($input as $value) {
        $var_rating[$value] = 0;
        foreach ($input as $test) {
            if ($value > $test) {
                     // ^  right here there is a hidden character, remove it and the code works fine
                $var_rating[$value] = $var_rating[$value] + 1;
            }
            else {}
        }
    }

    var_dump($var_rating);
?>
```

Comment: Thank You so much!!! You saved me. By the way.. What can I do to avoid having these hidden characters in my code?

Comment: @JanBayram Firstly, if this solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the outlined checkmark under the down arrow.  Secondly, use an IDE or a code editor which can highlight such things.  I used Notepad++ to find this, as when I selected the line, it listed 26 characters, when there should be 25.  That is how I figured out where it was.

Comment: Well, I use Coda 2 on my Mac. And how do I even type these characters?

Comment: @JanBayram Usually they are copied by accident from another source, which uses special characters to assist in formatting.  Either that, or you accidentally typed a certain key combination.

Comment: @Jan: you could have accidentally copied this character, for example. By the way, re-typing the whole line, as suggested by Daedalus would also have solved the problem :)

Comment: @JanBayram You too, happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a non-breaking space instead of a usual space in line 8, between `>` and `$test`. 
Replace it wit a usual space characted and it will be fine. 
Use an advanced text editor like [PsPad](http://pspad.com), which provides a possibility to view non-printable characters instead of notepad :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just for better showing the cause of this error, I used [Frhed](http://sourceforge.net/projects/frhed/?source=dlp)

There is hidden `Â` character :)

[image]